# Selenium can't locate this element

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on an element on a Web site by a couple of methods: ID, Relative, and Absolute XPath.  Each of these methods fail because the HTML for the page is set up as a single page application and there are several of these buttons with the same ID, etc.  I am wondering what I can do to get around this to be able to click the button since Selenium is having a hard time differentiating between the several similar buttons.

Here is some HTML for the element:

```
<div id="page-15" class="page active-page" style="position: absolute; left: 0px;">
    <div class="main-page">
        <div class="content-page">
            <div class="head"></div>
            <div class="page-body" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(244, 244, 244);"></div>
            <div class="bottom">
                <button id="wotc-button" class="form-right wotc-button wotc-button-ja ui-button ui-widget ui…ate-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only ui-state-focus" role="button" name="wotc-button" aria-disabled="false"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

The button I am trying to select is the one with `id="wotc-button"`

Relative XPath: `.//*[@id='wotc-button']`

Absolute XPath: `html/body/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[17]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/label`

The methods that I'm using to find this element is:

```
public static WebElement waitFindById(String id) { return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(id))); }

public static WebElement waitFindByXpath(String xpath) { return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath))); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a button in an "active page" only:

```
By.cssSelector("div.active-page button#wotc-button")
```

Comment: This seems to have the same effect as my previous attempts.  It still moves on to the next step in the script as if it finds the `wotc-button`, but it never clicks the button to proceed to the next page causing an error.

Comment: @lmcphers ok, was is correctly to assume that `active-page` class is only on a single page and that helps to uniquely identify the desired button?..

Comment: The class is `"page active-page"`, not just `"active-page"`.  Does that matter?  But it does appear that this is true.  The rest of the pages have divs with classes of just `"page"`

Comment: @lmcphers good, this means that we've correctly located the button. You probably have a different problem now..

Comment: Why is it not clicking the button?  It works the first time I use it, but not any time afterwards.

Comment: @lmcphers it's difficult to tell without being able to reproduce the problem..could it be that the page becomes not present or invisible once you click the button once? What errors do you get? Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83772/discussion-between-lmcphers-and-alecxe).